# Python Django custom template tags register.assignment_tag not working

Tags: python, django, django-templates

This is my Code for Python Django custom template tags

```
from django import template
from ipc.declarations.models import MainDeclaration
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

register = template.Library()


def section_settings(declarationId,user):
    declaration = get_object_or_404(MainDeclaration, pk=declarationId, user=user)
    businessInfo = declaration.GetOrCreateBusinessInfo()
    sections = declaration.GetSections()

    return sections

register.assignment_tag(section_settings)
```

Now i am getting a error

`register.assignment_tag(section_settings)
[Thu Jan 09 06:50:44 2014] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] AttributeError: 'Library' object has no attribute 'assignment_tag'`

This works fine with my development server application , but not working while uploading the same code in Production server.

Please guide me.

Comment: Do you have different django versions?

Comment: What Django version are you using in production? `assignment_tag` was added in 1.4.

Comment: @Daniel Roseman it is 1.3

Comment: @Daniel Roseman what is the substitute ?

Comment: Firstly, upgrade your production environment - 1.3 is three years old. Secondly, use the same version in development as you do in production.

Comment: That is bit time consuming for now @Daniel Roseman , can you guide me for the 1.3 version replacement for it

Answer (score 51):

Even though this question is a few years old, people recently may be seeing this error again, but for a different reason. Here's the error again:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Library' object has no attribute 'assignment_tag'
> ```

You may be seeing this error after upgrading to Django 2.0. This is because [`assignment_tag` was deprecated in Django 1.9](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/releases/1.9/#assignment-tag), and removed in Django 2.0:

> Django 1.4 added the `assignment_tag` helper to ease the creation of template tags that store results in a template variable. The `simple_tag()` helper has gained this same ability, making the `assignment_tag` obsolete. Tags that use `assignment_tag` should be updated to use `simple_tag`.

Note that the behaviour of `simple_tag` is similar but not identical to `assignment_tag` in Django 1.8.

Answer (score 3):

Just got this same error with package social_widgets, Python 3.7  and Django 2.2. Changing assignment_tag to simple_tag in social_widgets.py solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into this during an upgrade to Django 2. The problem showed up in `django-debug-toolbar` but was actually corrected by updating `django-webpack-loader` to the latest version.