# Installing webpack_loader (webpack-template-loader) gives attribute error on assignment_tag

Tags: django, webpack

I'm trying to add webpack-template-loader to my project (djang=2.2.1, django-webpack-loader===0.2.4, webpack-bundle-tracker=^0.4.3,webpack=^4.41.2).  To the best of my ability, I've followed the instructions [here](https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader).

My settings.py looks like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'webpack_loader',
]


# webpack loader
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'assets'),
)

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'CACHE': False,
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'assets/',
        'POLL_INTERVAL': 0.1,
        'TIMEOUT': None,
        'IGNORE': [r'.+\.hot-update.js', r'.+\.map']
    }
}
```

in my package.json I have the following:

```
{
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config ./webpack/prod.config.js",
        "build-dev": "webpack --config ./webpack/dev.config.js --display-error-details"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "webpack": "^4.41.2",
        "webpack-bundle-tracker": "^0.4.3",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.9"
    }
}
```

and running `npm run build-dev` correctly builds my bundle without error.  On adding `'webpack_loader'` to `INSTALLED_APPS` my server stops turning and i get the error:

```
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 66, in __getitem__
    return self._engines[alias]
KeyError: 'django'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 390, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 377, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 72, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/checks.py", line 79, in check_dependencies
    for engine in engines.all():
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in all
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 90, in <listcomp>
    return [self[alias] for alias in self]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/utils.py", line 81, in __getitem__
    engine = engine_cls(params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 25, in __init__
    options['libraries'] = self.get_templatetag_libraries(libraries)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 43, in get_templatetag_libraries
    libraries = get_installed_libraries()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 108, in get_installed_libraries
    for name in get_package_libraries(pkg):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/template/backends/django.py", line 121, in get_package_libraries
    module = import_module(entry[1])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/webpack_loader/templatetags/webpack_loader.py", line 50, in <module>
    @register.assignment_tag
AttributeError: 'Library' object has no attribute 'assignment_tag'
```

I'm struggling to work this out, I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21021690/python-django-custom-template-tags-register-assignment-tag-not-working) question on the depricated assignment tag, but I'm not sure how, or where to override this, and from the error message, it seems to be a byproduct of a problem with bootstrap, not the root cause.

Can someone please explain why I am seeing this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I'm adding this as an answer to close the question, but it's not particularly satisfactory, so if anyone want's to add logic behind this I'll definitely change the accepted answer for a better one.*

The issue was to do with the imports, and specifically in the was webpack_loader treated `assignment_tag`, as it should have imported:

```
assignment_tag = register.simple_tag if VERSION >= (1, 9) else register.assignment_tag
@assignment_tag
def get_files(bundle_name, extension=None, config='DEFAULT'):
    ...
```

for whatever reason the ternary operator was nor regiatering version as > 1.9.

When we added the repo like an app (rather than using pipenv) the problem disappeared.

Not a wonderful solution, but a solution none the less